# Howto tell Carrierwave remote_image_url to use a http proxy server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, proxy-server

I can not figure out howto tell carrierwave to use a proxy server:

```
export http_proxy='http://bar.com:3128'
```

does not work with

```
SomeModel.remote_photo_url = 'http://foo.com/path/to/image.jpg'
```

The production server is behind a firewall, which does not allow outgoing requests and requires the usage of a http proxy server to allow the download of images from http://foo.com

Is there a way to tell carrierwave to use an http proxy?

Answer (score -1):

Based on the information on [this blog post](http://jakcharlton.github.io/blog/2012/09/14/carrierwave-errors-with-http-proxy/), you need to add a trailing slash to your proxy url.

```
export http_proxy='http://bar.com:3128/'
```